# What is the last character of a line string (hexadecimal) in a file which is written using echo

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a file test.txt

```
$cat text.txt
0xee8745a2
0xfec6a2ea
0x0ae45a4b
```

Which is created using echo in linux

Ex:

```
echo 0xee8745a2 > text.txt
echo 0xfec6a2ea >> text.txt
```

When i use `fgets()`,I am getting length of the buffer 11.

What "echo" is appending to each line when writing to file.

Comment: `fgets()` does not create a buffer. You have to provide a buffer that is long enough and limit the input so that this buffer never overflows. The buffer size can be whatever, for example 300, this does not mean the input will fill that buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` outputs its argument followed by a newline character (`\n` aka LF aka 0x10).  So that's the extra character you're seeing.  To suppress this, use `echo -n 0xfec6a2ea > test.txt`, but then of course all the text will be on the same line.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nate Eldredge. have few more doubts like, when echo is used with double quotes and without quotes,Is there any difference?

Comment: Using `printf '%s' 0xfec6a2ea > test.txt` is better than depending on random echo implementations supporting the non-standard `-n` option.

Comment: @ShashikanthAcharya: The quotes are parsed by the shell and `echo` never sees them.  But they may protect special characters from being interpreted by the shell before they reach `echo`.